# Meaning of “She wheedled her mother into buying John a mink coat ”?

Tags: prepositions

What does "She wheedled her mother into buying John a mink coat" mean?

Does it mean "She wheedled her mother and her mother bought a mink coat and her mother gave John a mink coat" or "She wheedled her mother and her mother bought a mink coat from John"?

I think "wheedle" is "persuade"

Comment: Do you know what the verb _wheedle_ means? Please use the [edit] link to tell us about the research you have done on your own. This will help us to provide a useful answer!

Comment: Very good! _Wheedle_ is a little stronger than _persuade,_ though. When I _wheedle_ someone into doing something, it means that I might "stroke" the other person. I might be very persistent, maybe even a little annoying. I might flatter or joke with the other person. _Wheedling_ is very close to _pleading_ and _bargaining,_ or _dickering._ OED says: _To entice or persuade by soft flattering words; to gain over or take in by coaxing or cajolery._ ([edit]ing your question is exactly the right way to add information!)

Comment: Do you know what it means to _persuade_ another person? Do you understand what "She" persuaded her mother to do?

Answer (score 1):

You are somewhat correct about 'wheedle'; it means, roughly, 'to beg, whine, and plead constantly until you get what you want'.

Additionally, I guess that you are confused over the ditransitive use of 'buy' (that is, 'buy' with both a direct object, 'a mink coat', which is the thing being bought, and an indirect object, 'John', who is the recipient of the action).

An indirect object can always be replaced by a prepositional phrase, like so:

> I gave John a hint  --> I gave a hint to John.
>   I told John a story --> I told a story to John.
>   I made John a sandwich --> I made a sandwich for John.
>   I brought John an umbrella --> I brought an umbrella for John.

When transforming a sentence in this fashion, the preposition is almost always *to* or *for*, depending on the verb, because the indirect object is almost always *receiving* the direct object as a result of the verb.

So, the correct interpretation of your sentence is

> She begged and pleaded with her mother until her mother bought a mink coat for John.

A little light reading about indirect objects is available at http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/indirectobject.htm .

Answer (score 0):

> She wheedled her mother into buying John a mink coat.

It is similar to

> She persuaded her mother to buy John a mink coat.

In both sentences

*She* is the subject

*wheedled/persuaded* is the main verb

*her mother* is the direct object of the main verb

The phrases *into buying John a mink coat* and *to buy John a mink coat* are complements of their respective verbs.

In these phrases, *mink coat* is the direct object of *buying/to buy*. It tells *what* the mother bought. *John* is the indirect object of *buying/to buy*. This tells *for whom* the mink coat was bought. So, John does not do any selling here.